# sending response in message passing on history search

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to send search history in the background page and send response back to front page. I am using message parsing . 
I am unable to send response back after searching history.

--------background.js-------------

```
var SECONDS_PER_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request === "getHistory"){
        var value = getHistory();
        console.log("Response" , value);
        sendResponse(value);    
} 
}
```

);

```
function getHistory(){
var current_time = new Date().getTime();
var timeToFetch = current_time - SECONDS_PER_WEEK;
return chrome.history.search({
        'text' : '',
        'startTime' : timeToFetch
    },
    function(resp){
        return resp;
});
```

}

The problem lies here itself as on logging I get 'undefined' as response.
Can anyone direct me to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the `Chrome.*` API functions are asynchronous so try doing it something like this:

**background.js**

```
var SECONDS_PER_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request === "getHistory"){
    getHistory(sendResponse);
    return true;
  } 
});

function getHistory(sendResponse){
  var current_time = new Date().getTime();
  var timeToFetch = current_time - SECONDS_PER_WEEK;
  chrome.history.search({
    'text' : '',
    'startTime' : timeToFetch
  },
  function(resp){
    console.log("Response: " + resp);
    sendResponse(resp);
  });
}
```